# Share Data Studio Report with anyone on the internet but make them enter credentials to view it

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I have created a Data studio report using my personal community connector as a data source.

This connector requires `"authType": ["USER_PASS"]`, so I need to enter credentials when I try to use the connector to access the data.

But let's say I want to share the Report with someone(or a group of people) who doesn't have a Google account, but I also want only those people to see it.

I am storing my credentials using `PropertiesService.getUserProperties()` but opening the shareable link in incognito mode still displays the data using the saved credentials.

I tried setting **Data Credentials** to **Viewer’s Credentials** but that just forces me to login to a Google account.

I have read about sending token via URL but that won't fit my use case as getData() call isn't made every time someone access the report.

Is there any way I could make users use `"authType": ["USER_PASS"]` to view my data?

Comment: Could you explain why "getData() call isn't made every time someone access the report"?

Comment: `getAuthType()` and `isAuthValid()` requests are made when someone access the requests and not `getData()`. `getData()` is made when I refresh the data(which can only be done my me) . I thought this behavior is expected as my refresh data time is set to 12 hours. Is it not? Is Data Studio supposed to fetch data for every view? If yes, then is there a way to cache the data if I have large data?